# Using AWS CodeBuild or Lambda to run jasmine tests before deployment

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, jasmine-node, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

Folks,
  Have been trying to figure out the correct way to fire of a CodeBuild project which either produces the artifact after compiling and running jasmine tests, or fails and stops the CodePipeline from proceeding with deployment.

If my `buildspec.yml` looks like:

```
version: 0.1

phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - echo Installing... Running npm install
      - npm install
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo pre_build...
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Testing... Running npm test
      - npm test
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
```

How should I fail out of the `npm test` phase?  If any of the jasmine tests fail during `npm test`, will the artifact still be produced?

Another thought I have is to have the following occur if any of the tests fail:

```
    var params = {
        jobId: jobId,
        failureDetails: {
            message: JSON.stringify(message),
            type: 'JobFailed',
            externalExecutionId: context.invokeid
        }
    };
    codepipeline.putJobFailureResult(params, function(err, data) {
        ...
    });
```

or send a stop signal to CodeBuild?

```
var params = {
  id: 'STRING_VALUE' /* required */
};
codebuild.stopBuild(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

Or how do I terminate the build to not produce the artifact?  Maybe I got this wrong, and it should be a Lambda function that kicks off the unit tests.  I am not sure if Lambda is ideal for this, as I can imagine some services take a while to finish the unit tests

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone stumbles upon this, both ways will work.  AWS CodeBuild will fail on any non-zero exit status code.  Thus, any tests that fail will cause the pipeline to fail.

Same can be done with lambda